Git gui is not showing on already exsisting project on my Windows 10 lap?
I cloned a project and start to develop from Git gui. But in the next day when i try to open the git gui in the project directory it is not showing the gui. But it's icon is already appear in the task bar. Even it is not appear when click on the taskbar icon.
I can open git gui from other locations but cant open in existing projects. When i open elsewhere and select the previous repository it already hide and cant find the gui.
I develop a java ee project using netbeans.
But git bash can open inside the project directory. Is there any solution?

Git gui records some information in the project's .git/config file. Try removing these lines (as shown below). The program window is probably being shown off-screen if you used to have two monitors and now have a different setup. Removing these will allow it to start using defaults for size, position and window state.
[gui]
        wmstate = normal
        geometry = 1626x800+202+82 470 392

